# Custom Typeface not working

Tags: java, android

I have a tutorial for basic animation that I am doing currently.  The code was working before I tried to include a custom typeface within the code.  I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me.  Bellow I have included the LogCat and my typeface code.

```
Typeface font;

public MyBringBack(Context context) {
    super(context);

    gPlus = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plusselected);
    changingY = 0;
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "G-Unit");

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setARGB(50,254,10,500);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setTextSize(50);
    textPaint.setTypeface(font);
    canvas.drawText("mybringback",canvas.getWidth()/2, 200, textPaint);
```

LogCat:-

```
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learn.tam/com.example.learn.tam.GFX}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)  
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:247)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:221)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at com.example.learn.tam.MyBringBack.<init>(MyBringBack.java:25)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at com.example.learn.tam.GFX.onCreate(GFX.java:14)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-06 12:31:25.395: E/AndroidRuntime(19933):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "G-Unit.ttf");
```

instead

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "G-Unit");
```

u will need to pass  font file name with extension (like ttf,otf...) as second param to `Typeface.createFromAsset` method

Answer (score 0):

in createFromAsset use the extension name of the custom font.